# Scipy rankdata reverse highest to lowest

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What I am trying to achieve is a 'highest to lowest' ranking of a list of values, basically the reverse of rankdata

So instead of:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4]
rankdata(a).astype(int)
array([1, 2, 5, 7, 5, 2, 5, 7])
```

I want to get this:

```
array([7, 6, 3, 1, 3, 6, 3, 1])
```

I wasn't able to find anything in the rankdata documentation to do this.

Comment: isn't it just `len(a) - rankdata(...)`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to convert the result of `rankdata(a)` to integers?  When you use the default method, the ranks of tied values are the average of ordinal ranks of the tied values.  You might want to consider a method that returns integral values, such as `method='ordinal'`, or in fact any method *except* the default, which is `'average'`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Possible a stupid answer you don't want, but can't you just subtract the length, i.e., 'reverse' from high to low rank?

```
a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4]
len(a) - rankdata(a).astype(int)
array([7, 6, 3, 1, 3, 6, 3, 1])
```

Comment: Useful to note that this method only works when the default method='average' is used.  If you were to use method='min', this would not work for the following sequence, as an example: [1,2,2,3,4,5].

Answer (score 10):

An alternative would be turning the list into negative numbers:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import rankdata
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4]
>>> rankdata([-1 * i for i in a]).astype(int)
array([8, 6, 4, 1, 4, 6, 4, 1])
```

I find this a more accurate approach, since the resolution of the ties is resolved in the sense of the inverted rank, and not in the sense of the natural rank. Additionally, in this case the smallest value gets the value of the last position of the list, as generally expected.

Answer (score 0):

be mindful with an issue with both of these answers, when you use argsort, it will lead to an inconsistent ordering which only appears if ties occur.

ex.

```
a=[1,1,2,3,4]

np.argsort(stats.rankdata(a))=array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=int64
np.argsort(stats.rankdata([-1*i for i in a])) = array([4, 3, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
np.argsort(5-stats.rankdata(a))= array([4, 3, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

notice that reversing causes an inconsistency in tie ordering (0 and 1) are not flipped as they are in the original.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two simple ways do this, but there are some subtleties to take into account, which I'll point out along the way.

Converting to int isn't a good idea unless the original ranking were all integer, in which case you don't need it! The default method for treating ties in `rankdata()` is `"average"`, which will result in fractional ranks if there are ties. That's presumably the reason for the conversion to integer in the question. If you use one of the other methods, i.e. `"max"`, `"min"`, or `"ordinal"`, then the ranks will already be integer. I'm going to assume that that is acceptable to the OP, and use `method="max"` from here and on.

### Reverse after ranking (faster)

In this approach we rank first, and then reverse the order

```
len(a) - rankdata(a, method="max") + 1
```

which gives

```
[8 6 3 1 3 6 3 1]
```

The `+ 1` is needed since the maximum rank returned by `rankdata()` is `len(a)` but we want our minimum rank to never be 0. Note that even though we originally ranked using `"max"` for resolving ties, we get `"min"` behavior, due to the reversal. For example, the two occurrences of 2 are effectively at ranks 6 and 7 and were both assigned 6, which is the minimum of those ranks, not the maximum.

### Reverse before ranking (slower)

This approach requires iterating over the list to multiply the values by -1, which slows things down:

```
rankdata([-el for el in a], method="max")
```

which gives

```
array([8, 7, 5, 2, 5, 7, 5, 2])
```

In this case we do actually get `"max"` behavior, for example, the two occurrences of 2 are effectively at ranks 6 and 7 and were both assigned 7, which is the maximum of those ranks. This is what caused the rank 1 not to appear, since we have a tie at ranks 1 and 2, which gets the rank 2, which is the maximum of those two ranks.

### Timing

If you are looking to do this on long inputs, and speed is an issue, it's quite clear that the first method should be faster. For example, if we use the input:

```
a = numpy.random.randint(100, size=1000).tolist()
```

Then we get:

```
%timeit len(a) - rankdata(a, method="max") + 1
90.5 µs ± 3.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit rankdata([-el for el in a], method="max")
121 µs ± 1.65 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```